# Multiple timestamps when a value in one cell changes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to record multiple changes that is made in one cell in column A. In my example I have a user that would enter the date and time in column A5. Later on the user might change the value in this same cell (A5). This change could happen up to 5 times. How do I record the date and time of all 5 these changes starting in column AH.

So the first change in A5 should be recorded in column AH5, the second change in A5 should be recorded in column AI5, and so on.

I found multiple macros but they only timestamp the date and time the change in the same cell every time.

Comment: Can you please post the macro code that you are currently working with? That way we can modify the existing code to record in adjacent cells.

Comment: Let's assume that user has opened saved workbook, then further `A5` changes should be recorded starting from `AH5` as first change? Or starting the first empty cell in `AH5:AL5`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following code to your target worksheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static RecCell As Range
    If Target.Address = "$A$5" Then
        Select Case True
        Case RecCell Is Nothing
            Set RecCell = Target.Parent.Range("AH5")
            RecCell.Value = Target.Value
        Case RecCell.Column < Target.Parent.Range("AL5").Column
            Set RecCell = RecCell.Offset(0, 1)
            RecCell.Value = Target.Value
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: worksheet change event handler]

Then the first `A5` change in opened workbook will be saved to `AH5`, and the next four changes to `AI5:AL5`, further changes will be ignored.

**UPDATE**

Here is the code meeting your last requirements. To make it flexible enough I've added some extra checks which are forbidding to record the value, if it's not a date or the same as the previously recorded. You can easily change those limitations by deleting corresponding `Case` statement lines - see my comments. Also it processes all changed cells if e. g. a copied cell has been pasted to several selected cells.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Add reference: Menu - Tools - References - Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Static RecList As New Dictionary ' dictionary stores a number of column last record have been made for each row
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Target ' loop through all cells that have been changed
        With Cell
            Select Case True
            Case .Column <> 1 ' exit if column is not A
                Exit Sub
            Case .Row < 5 Or .Row > 205 ' exit if row is out of target range
                Exit Sub
            Case Not IsDate(.Value) ' exit if changed value hasn't got a date format
                Exit Sub
            Case Not RecList.Exists(.Row) ' first change in this row
                RecList(.Row) = Range("AH:AH").Column ' start recording from AH, proceed with value assigning
            Case .Parent.Cells(.Row, RecList(.Row)) = .Value ' exit if current entered value is the same as the previous
                Exit Sub
            Case RecList(.Row) < Range("AL:AL").Column ' the previous populated column is less than AL
                Set RecList(.Row) = RecList(.Row) + 1 ' continue recording, shift right, proceed with value assigning
            Case Else ' exit if the previous populated column is AL
                Exit Sub
            End Select
            .Parent.Cells(.Row, RecList(.Row)) = .Value ' assign the value from changed cell
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Wiil do. Question: How do I extend the range if the user are making changes to rows A5 to A205 and the time stamps in the corresponding rows 5 to 205? Your code above is limited to row 5 (which was what I asked for in the Q.) Tx.

Comment: @bertusg, that requires a minor change, I'll update my answer in few hours. Also pls take a look at my comment for your question.