# Multiple time stamps for each cell change

Tags: excel, vba, timestamp

I am trying to modify the code mentioned here:
[Multiple timestamps when a value in one cell changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32440948/multiple-timestamps-when-a-value-in-one-cell-changes)

Basically, instead of inserting the new timestamp changes for each cell on five different columns of the same row, I wish to add each new timestamp (with its new value appended to it) to the beginning of a string in one column using a semicolon delimeter for each .01 decrease of each cell in the dynamically changing column. Timestamp additions would be unlimited.

For example, if A1 changed from 5.01 to 5.00, B1 will contain 5.00 - new timestamp; (previous values and timestamps)

I only wish to capture changes where the value in column A decreases. So if A2 went from 6.53 to 6.54, capture nothing, but if it went from the 6.54 straight to 6.51, add three new timestamps to B2:

6.53- new timestamp; 6.52- new timestamp; 6.51- new timestamp;(previous values and timestamps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate() 'variant
     Static dictSt As New Dictionary
       'reset the dictionary by putting the string "Reset" in range "C1" and pressing Enter
       Dim lastRow As Long
       lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
       If Range("C1") = "Reset" Then
           Application.EnableEvents = False
            Range("D1").ClearContents
            Range("B2:B" & lastRow).ClearContents
           Application.EnableEvents = True
            dictSt.RemoveAll
            Exit Sub
       End If
       
       'processing_____________________________________________________
       Dim rng As Range, Target As Range, dif As Double, i As Long
       Dim dblIncrement As Double
    
       Set rng = Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
       
       Application.EnableEvents = False
       For Each Target In rng
         If Not dictSt.Exists(Target.Address) Then
            dictSt.Add Target.Address, Array(Target.Value & "-" & Format(Now(), "hh:mm:ss"), Target.Value)
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = dictSt(Target.Address)(0)
         Else
             Debug.Print dictSt(Target.Address)(1)
             If Target.Value < CDbl(dictSt(Target.Address)(1)) Then
                    'set records of 0.01 increments:
                    dif = dictSt(Target.Address)(1) - Target.Value
                    dblIncrement = Round(dif / 0.01, 0): ' How many 0.01 increments to be used
                    For i = 1 To dblIncrement
                         dictSt(Target.Address) = Array(dictSt(Target.Address)(1) _
                                 - 0.01 & "-" & Format(Now(), "hh:mm:ss") & ";" & dictSt(Target.Address)(0), dictSt(Target.Address)(1) - 0.01)
                    Next i
                    Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = dictSt(Target.Address)(0) 'fill the dict key value
                Else
                    dictSt(Target.Address) = Array(dictSt(Target.Address)(0), Target.Value)
                End If
         End If
       Next
       Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub
```

You, probably, will make some tests. In order to reset the used dictionary for working environment, you must write "Reset" in "C1" and press `Enter`. If "C1" is inconvenient, the code can easily be adapted to use any other cell, or any other string (maybe shorter) to reset....

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219069/discussion-on-answer-by-faneduru-multiple-time-stamps-for-each-cell-change).

Comment: Added a new code, which creates time stamps for all increasing (in C:C column). I understood/deduced that you would like such a behavior... If you do not need it, you can comment or delete the lines starting from `If Target.Offset(0, 2).Value = "" Then`...

Comment: The previous code had the correct values but only one timestamp for each value. This code fixes the timestamp issue but now the values are a bit off. Basically, once a change occurs, the first addition to the string is correct as it subtracts .1 from the initial value. But the subsequent string additions do not continue to subtract .1. Rather, the remainong values are all the same for the given timestamp. This value appears to be the new value -.10.

Comment: @michael: Please, try giving me a reproductibile example which does not behave what you need.

Comment: h2 has initial value of 5.3, i2 has initial value of 7. Changed h2 to 5. B2 produces 11.9-17:08:38;11.9-17:08:38;12.2-17:08:38;12.3-17:07:33. This should actually be 12-17:08:38;12.1-17:08:38;12.2-17:08:38;12.3-17:07:33

Comment: @michael: Yes, you are right. I forgot to also decrease 1 from the second array element. The code became a little more complex and I had to be more attentive... I will adapt it in some seconds. I know what is about...

Comment: @michael: Adapted. Please, check it now. It already became a kind of Odyssey... :)

Comment: Same issue as before

Comment: @michael: Try the updated version, please... Do not forget to update the page (this one)...

Comment: Quite confused. If I can see your comment that means the page has been updated? I refreshed the page, is this what you mean? Anyway, the result is not quite the same as the previous one. The remaining values are .2 less the new value now instead of .1 before. The first value shown on the cell should actually be the new value in column A after the other remaining values have decreased by .01 down to it.

Comment: @michael: No, if you can see the comments this does not mean that the page (containing the code) has been refreshed... But, now I approved an edit you made and it came back to the not modified code... Let me correct it again...

Comment: @michael: Corrected... Please, try the new version. Sometimes, the page is refreshed by itself, but this process looks to be done with a specific frequency. In order to be on the safe side, I would recommend to refresh the page before copying the code.

Comment: You've done it man. Thanks a bunch for the help. Not sure what you get out of helping me and being so attentive, but I very much appreciate it.

Comment: @michael:  Glad I could help!